# Undefined method or local variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

```
undefined local variable or method `requestuser_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f92de073e10>:0x007f92e191a020>
```

I don't know why this error occurs even though I route to the required controller and the view is also no problem here.

```
# routes.rb

resources :users do 
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end
end

resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
#resources :requests, only: [:create]

root to: 'static_pages#home'

match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'    
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
match '/request', to: 'users#requestuser'
```

The named route:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to "Requests", requestuser_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

UsersController:

```
def requestuser
  @title = "Requests"
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

I think there is an error in the named route as I am new to Rails. I don't know what is the cause of error. The named route is predefined or how does it work.

I need to learn more topics on Rails can someone tell which is the best site to learn after beginner stage.

Comment: what is the version of Rails?

Comment: You don't have `requestuser` named route defined anywhere, so no wonder you get an error.

Comment: You can use `rails routes` in the console if you are unsure what routes exist or how they are named.

Comment: try this:- **match '/request', to: 'users#requestuser', via: [:get, :post], as: :requestuser**, your code will work as it is without any change , just need to add **as: :requestuser** in your route.

Answer (score 1):

The `requestuser_path` route helper method does not exist.

Unless specified, route helper methods are autogenerated in Rails. To see a list of all these helpers and their corresponding controllers and actions, go to http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes assuming you are running your development Rails server on port 3000.

In your case, the method you are looking for is `request_path`, not `requestuser_path`

To learn more about routes in Rails, the official documentation is a good resource. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Why it looks for request_path though i gave users#requestuser

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use ruby keyword as routes or any controller's or model's name. Ruby will throw error. Try to rename the routes "match '/request', to: 'users#requestuser'"

Answer (score 0):

1. It's always a good practice to run `rails routes` or `rake routes` to see how rails generates your routes, in your case pleas use `request_path`
2. It's not recommended to use `match` and even considered invalid in newer rails version:

> If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option.
>   If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router:
>     Instead of: match "controller#action"
>     Do: get "controller#action"